# IBM Worklight - .war builder using wrong Java version

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've setup Worklight Studio to use JDK 1.6 in my Worklight project.

I also changed the "compilation compliance level" to 1.6.

Eclipse is started with jdk/jre 1.6.

Despite all of this, the `war` is generated with Java 1.7!!!

My `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` variables are also set to my JDK/JRE 1.6.

I'm operating under Windows 7 (64 bit).

How can I tell Worklight to build the `war` with jdk 1.6, not the default Windows one?

Comment: How do you know that war is generated using java 1.7?. Also, if you have change the JAVA_HOME and not yet restarted the your IDE, then try restarting your IDE.

Comment: MANIFEST.MF tells me "Created-By: 1.7.0_10-b18 (Oracle Corporation)" and when i run it in my server with jre1.6: unsupported version 51...

Comment: Note: Please always add the worklight tag in addition to any other worklight-related tags.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, navigate to `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs`. Make sure JRE v6 is the version that is to be used (also try to remove and re-add it, maybe it's some stuck configuration option...).

This is the JRE version Eclipse will use to generate the .war file in your Worklight project.

For good measure, delete your existing .war file before generating a new one after changing the above.